# angularjs and ionic - Android Local Notification

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, android-notifications, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with Android mobile notifications.
I am using Angularjs and ionic framework.

I want to work with local notifications and I use this plugin. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

my code

```
var app = angular.module('Forex', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']) 
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$http,$interval, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
scope.notification = function () {
$cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title here',
        text: 'Text here'
      });
    };
```

But if I press the button to call the scope.

```
<ion-toggle ng-click="notification()">Enable Notifier</ion-toggle>
```

I get this error. Cordobva is not defined.

```
ReferenceError: $cordova is not defined
at Scope.$scope.notification (http://192.168.1.175:8100/js/app.js:48:1)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:227)
at http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57514:9
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24772:23)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57513:13)
at HTMLDivElement.eventHandler (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12098:21)
at triggerMouseEvent (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2865:7)
at tapClick (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2854:3)
at HTMLDocument.tapMouseUp (http://192.168.1.175:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2927:5)
```

Please say so if I miss some info to give. After years this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I also tried

```
    $scope.notification = function () {
     $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Dynamic Notification',
                    text: 'txt'
                }).then(function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                });
            }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

The apparent thing in your example is that `$cordova` is undefined.

`$cordova`  most likely need to be included as a dependency in the controller arguments.

try:

```
app.controller("MainCtrl",
   function($scope,$http,$interval, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification, $cordova) {
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples#samples) for this plugin it looks like cordova is not passed as an angular dependency but rather is a global object:

```
var app = angular.module('Forex', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $http, $interval, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
    scope.notification = function() {
        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id: 1,
            title: 'Title here',
            text: 'Text here'
        });
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

In [this example](https://github.com/learning-ionic/Chapter-7/blob/87d1dbdda95d5d5be266e6e25831fcbb0a2511ca/example33/www/js/app.js#L21-L32) we see the use of `$cordovaLocalNotification`,  wrapped in a `$ionicPlatform` ready call, your code would look like:

```
var app = angular.module('Forex', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $http, $interval, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

        $scope.notifText = 'Hello World!';

        $scope.triggerNotification = function () {

            $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: 'Dynamic Notification',
                text: $scope.notifText
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction but I get an error.        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaProvider <- $cordova <- MainCtrl

Comment: @user2804809 right, maybe cordova is called without the `$`?

Comment: cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule instead of $cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule

Comment: Out of pure desperation I already tried that days ago. With and without $

Comment: @user2804809 I made an update to the answer based on this example on github: https://github.com/learning-ionic/Chapter-7/blob/87d1dbdda95d5d5be266e6e25831fcbb0a2511ca/example33/www/js/app.js#L21-L32

Comment: I get an error back   TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at Object.schedule (file:///C:/Users/Romano/FX/www/js/ng-cordova.min.js:8:23787)
    at Scope.$scope.notification (file:///C:/Users/Romano/FX/www/js/app.js:48:28)       ...................................                            $scope.notification = function () {
 $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
                id: 1,
                title: 'Dynamic Notification',
                text: 'txt'
            }).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }


});

Comment: @Romano sounds like something isn't setup correctly. I suggest creating another post with the problem you are having this time, describing which tutorial you followed to set it up, and generally as much information as possible.